# Can't find my Data after Re-Installing WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

i'm having trouble with my WAMPserver, so here is the problem, i am upgrading my WAMP with the new version so i uninstalled my wamp and reinstall it again with the new version, and I forgot to make backup for my data

the current version is wampserver 2.5 64bit, mysql 5.6.17
i still have all the frm, myi, myd, ibdata0, ibdata1, ibdata etc
and in the localhost/phpmyadmin, my table showed up but i can't access it giving error sign "#1146 table xx.xxx doesn't exist", and that also means i can't see my data

i am using InnoDB table, are my data gone? or i still can recover it?

any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What version did you have before your current install?

Comment: And did you delete the old `\wamp\....` folder structure

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that your data is all gone. Your table is there because it kept a structure of previous schema. Not sure if you can recover it.

Why do you have to uninstall before install the latest one? You can just install on top of an existing installation I guess and it will only upgrade your version.

Always remember the best way is to do regular backups.
Use a scheduler or cron to automate this thing and put the backup into a cloud drive just to be safe.

(Sorry if I'm wrong. Long time since I used WAMP )

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows 7, have you tried right clicking on the folder the data files are stored in, and clicking "Restore to previous version"? If that option is available, it can save your butt in a case like this. I think it depends on windows system restore settings, but it's worth a shot.